# Android accelerometer

Tags: java, android, accelerometer

Is it just me or can I not find a simple tutorial on accessing the accelerometer in android via google search?
Every other time I search for some simple tutorial(countdowntimers, activities, handlers, threads) I can find some but for some reason the accelerometer subject is vague.
I use the examples from the sdk as a second or 3rd source once I get a clearer understanding from a simpler(as in for beginners) source, which are the sample tutorials other's provide on their blogs/site.
Where can I get a simple accelerometer tutorial?
Two books that I own don't have anything on the matter either.

Comment: a good example to use accelerometer in android http://www.quicktips.in/get-accelerometer-readings-android/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

have you tried this one 
https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtutorials/tree/master/38-Sensors  ?

Comment: I did find this tutorial but the OP was back in 2008. I started reading his tutorial and applying it but some things were off. Importing android.hardware.Sensor works but plural "Sensors" does not.

Comment: i added a new link to a good one above

Comment: Page not found!

Answer (score 3):

This is a very helpful bit of documentation from the android API reference, note especially the low-pass filter which can be very useful for smoothing out jitter.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values

Answer (score 0):

[Professional Android Sensor Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118183487) by Milette is a good book for Android sensor programming.

If you don't want to buy it, you can always Google for an ebook.